# How can simplify my database?

Tags: database

I am working on a project in which I have generated a unique id of a customer with the customer's Last name's first letter. And stored it in a database in different tables as if customer's name starting with a then the whole information of the customer will stored in Registration_A table. As such I have created tables of Registration up to Z. But retrieving if data with such structure is quiet difficult. can you suggest me another method to save data so that retrieving become more flexible?

Answer (score 2):

Put all of your registration data into one table. There's absolutely no need for you to break it into alphabetical pieces like that unless you have some serious performance issues.

When querying for registration data, use SQL's `WHERE` clause to narrow down your results.

Comment: Even when you have serious performance problems, that's rarely the right answer (only in some very unusual circumstances). Add appropriate indexes.

Comment: And even then partitioning the single table might be a better approach than mutliple tables.

Comment: Thanks. The problem get solved. But another problem is I want make a search in the database for that I have written down code as below:

Comment: String fname=request.getParameter("firstName");
String lname=request.getParameter("lastName");
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:pat");
Statement stat1=conn.createStatement();

 rsobj=stat1.executeQuery("select FName,LName from Registration where FName like 'fname%' AND LName like 'lname%'");

while(rsobj.next())
{ %>

<table border=1>
<tr><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th></tr><tr><td><%=rsobj.getString("2")%></td><td><%=rsobj.getString("4")%></td></tr>
</table><%}}%>

Comment: @Samiksh So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: It isn't showing anything. The problem is not the code as its not giving any error message. But whats the problem i am not getting.

Comment: @Samiksh Check your application logs. It might be that your app server is just swallowing the exceptions and displaying an empty page to you, especially if that code is directly on a JSP page (which is not a good solution in the long run, BTW). Also make sure that you are actually running your code and not some empty page. Use some debugging tools if possible.

Comment: No nothing is happening. I did all efforts. How can I proceed if code want to run on html not on JSP can you please provide me any link to show JSP code not runing directly but as intermediate only. But if in a loop can this possible?

Comment: @Samiksh Try to google for "jsp hello world" and "servlet hello world" and choose any one of the tutorials which are found. If you can't get the JSP to at least print something, then there's something seriously wrong. Follow the tutorials which are most suited for your environment (app server, operating system etc) and get your app to do something. Then build from there and add database functionality.

Comment: select FName,LName from Registration where FName like 'fname%' ;      here in this query fname is a string its an object of string. If I want to compare FName with this object then what should I do?

Comment: @Samiksh So you have `String fname = // something` and you want to insert it into the SQL query? Just concatenate it normally: `String sql = "select FName, LName from Registration where FName like '" + fname + "%'"` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Hey thanks its working. But if I wish to use like and AND operator as in the query below then how can I use:                              select FName, LName from Registration where FName like '" + fname + "%' AND LName like '" + lname + "%'";

Comment: I got the solution that I must separate these queries with Union. Thanks a lot. I like this forum so much as I got solutions easily.

Answer (score 0):

You **have** to merge this to one table ´Registration´, then let the database care about unique ids. This depends on your database, but searching for `PRIMARY KEY` or `AUTO INCREMENT` should give you lots of results.

If you have done the the splitting because of performance reasons, you can add a `Index` on the users last name.